# Is javax.ejb still in used today?

Tags: java, ejb, cop

I am working on a project to build a stateless ejb calculator component and my very first error is that the **javax.ejb package does not exist** (even after I looked for and included the jar).
The thing is all solutions I am seeing online are old.....like from 2006, with the latest ones being 2013-2015. Which kinda makes it seem like an obsolete thing, and there's probably a better way of doing it. If so please advice me. I'm using the latest version of Apache Netbeans and JDK 15. Currently started the project with Java EE7(recommended in the tutorial I'm following) and GlassFish server.

Also I'm not sure if it all stems from the import error but when I try to add business logic, "Insert code " does not give me an "Add Business Method" option.

Comment: Background: There has been a [transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee). In practical terms, this means that libraries which used to be maintained using the `javax` package name, are now maintained using the `jakarta` package name. You can find the newest packages in Maven - for example, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jakarta+ejb).

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, finally adding the whole Java EE 7 API library worked. No more
**javax.ejb package does not exist** error and that has **fixed the no *Add Business Method* issue**
Would still appreciate help better methods of doing this (if they exist)